# update value use $each in mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

i need to update all seen value 0 to 1 
use mongo and php as array

```
enter code herearray (
  '_id' => new MongoId("5357c023dd34bcc9298b456e"),
  '_type' => 
  array (
    '0' => 'Altibbi_Mongo_MemberNotification',
  ),
  'member_id' => '53068',
  'notification_count' => new MongoInt32(30),
  'notifications' => 
  array (
    '0' => 
    array (
      'actor_id' => '0',
      'notification_type' => 'badge_top',
      'date_added' => '2014-04-23 16:29:07',
      'seen' => '0',
    ),
    '1' => 
    array (
      'actor_id' => '0',
      'notification_type' => 'badge_country',
      'date_added' => '2014-04-24 08:32:55',
      'seen' => '1',
    )
  ),
)
```

i need any help to fix the problem i use $ it update only single first value
i use $each and it does not work at all

Comment: Which problem? Why did you expect it to work in the first place? Can you reference the manual for the feature you're trying to use here?

Comment: $this->update(array('member_id'=>"53068" , "notifications.seen"=> "0"),
                       array('$set' => array('notification_count'=>0 ,'notifications.$.seen' => "1"));

Answer (score 0):

The [**positional `$`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator that you are trying to use will **only** update the **first** element that is matched from the query side of your update statement. This is currently by design and referred to in the documentation.

In order update multiple positions you must either:

1. Issue multiple update statements against the document until the modified count is returned as 0.
2. Retrieve the document and modify each element of the array to set your new value.

A typical coding example of the 2nd approach is along the lines of:

```
var doc = db.collection.findOne({ "member_id": "53068" })

for ( var x = 0; x < doc.notifications.length; x++ ) {
    if ( doc.notifications[x].seen == 0 ) {
        var obj = {};
        obj["notifications." + x] = 1;
        db.collection.update(
            { "member_id": "53068" },
            { "$set": obj }
        );
    }
}
```

The [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) operator you refer to is for specifying multiple array elements to use with other operators such as [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) and [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) which do not apply here as those are about creating new elements.